# Oracle 19c connection with python Listener refused connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle19c, python-oracledb

I'm using oracledb library as the cx_oracle is not working now, using the command oracledb.connect(), and it always gives error

here is my code:

```
connection = oracledb.connect(
     user='myusername',
     password='mypassword',
     dsn='xx.xx.xxx.xxx:portnumber/dsnname')
print("Successfully connected to Oracle Database")

oracledb.exceptions.OperationalError: DPY-6000: cannot connect to database. Listener refused connection. (Similar to ORA-12660)
```

and if I set the parameters like this

```
connection = oracledb.connect(
     user='myusername',
     password='mypassword',
     dsn='xx.xx.xxx.xxx:portnumber:dsnname')
print("Successfully connected to Oracle Database")
```

it returns error

```
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4027: no configuration directory to search for tnsnames.ora
```

the database administrator approved the variables are correct and we are using thin client which is the default in the code parameters so I don't know what is making the problem?

Comment: Has your DBA confirmed that the listener is actually running on that address and port? (The second error is because it's trying to interpret `dsn` as a TNS alias and you don't have TNS_ADMIN set; but as that's not what you're trying to achieve, focus on the first config and error.)

Comment: Yes, the listener is set correctly, how to have TNS_ADMIN set and what would that do?

Comment: You could put the connection info in a tnsnamea.ora file in a directory pointed to by TNS_ADMIN - so you could manage it outside code. It won't help with the error you're getting through. The listener data maybe set correctly in your connect string, but is the listener actually running - can you log in to that IP address and see it with `lsnrctl status`? And might there be an IP address conflict - e.g. if the address is a private one and you connect to it over a VPN, you could be hitting a local machine instead of the remote one you expect?

Comment: Thank you for that, but I don't think this is a right solution for my case, as this code is going to run on gcp and shall not have a specific file location to use

Comment: No, that's why I said to focus on the first config and error. I was just explaining what the second error meant. *8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error (ORA-12660) indicates that you have encryption or checksumming parameters set on the database. These are set up in the server side sqlnet.ora and look something like this:

```
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER=REQUIRED
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_SERVER=REQUIRED
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER=(AES256,AES192,AES128)
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_SERVER=(SHA1)
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT=REQUIRED
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_CLIENT=REQUIRED
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT=(AES256,AES192,AES128)
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_CLIENT=(SHA1)
```

This has been noted in the [documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/appendix_b.html#native-network-encryption-and-checksumming). Your only option is to either disable the server requirement for native network encryption (NNE) or enable thick mode (which works the same way as cx_Oracle).

You can follow along with this [enhancement request](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues/94) to see when NNE support is added to thin mode.

Comment: The parameters could also appear in a "client side" sqlnet.ora, but that may be uncommon.

Comment: unfortunately they can't change it to Thick mode, and they aren't using any encryptions on network layer, any help?

Comment: That error says that the server *insists* upon using encyrption/checksumming on the network layer -- so the only option is to disable the requirement or use thick mode. No other options exist, unfortunately!